# Can multiple datatables get data from same url?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is it possible to have two datatables in one view which point to the same Ajax url? At the moment i had to split this into two different calls, but i would like to get my data through one call.

How i have the calls at the moment:

```
var table1;
var table2;

if (!$.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable('#table1')) {
     table1 = $("#table1").DataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 4,
        "dom": "ftp",
        "ajax": {
            "url": "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Action1", "Controller", new { @id = @Model.ID}))",
            "dataSrc": "list1"
        },..});


if (!$.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable('#table2')) {
     table2 = $("#table2").DataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 4,
        "dom": "ftp",
        "ajax": {
            "url": "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Action2", "Controller", new { @id = @Model.ID}))",
            "dataSrc": "list2"
        },..});
```

But i would idealy like the ajax urls to be just one call and select the dataSrc from the data returned.

A little bit like this (pseudo code):

```
var table1;
var table2;
var url = "@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Action1", "Controller", new { @id = @Model.ID}))";

if (!$.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable('#table1')) {
     table1 = $("#table1").DataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 4,
        "dom": "ftp",
        "ajax": {
            "url": url,
            "dataSrc": "list1"
        },..});


if (!$.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable('#table2')) {
     table2 = $("#table2").DataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 4,
        "dom": "ftp",
        "ajax": {
            "url": url,
            "dataSrc": "list2"
        },..});
```

Is this possible to do? Are there any alternatives?

---

EDIT:

For people like me, who like the "Trying to get data" and "No data found" messages on the ajax call.

First Setup a default message in sEmptyTable

```
"oLanguage": {
    "sEmptyTable": "Looking for records, please wait."
},
```

And in the getJson call, manipulate this string to show a new message when the table returns empty.

```
$.getJSON("@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("Action1", "Controller", new {id = @Model.ID}))", function (json) {
    if (json.list1.length > 0) { table1.rows.add(json.list1).draw(); }

    if (json.list2.length > 0) { table2.rows.add(json.list2).draw(); }

    if (json.list1.length == 0) {
            table1.context[0].oLanguage.sEmptyTable = "No records found.";
            table1.draw();
        }

    if (json.list2.length == 0) {
            table2.context[0].oLanguage.sEmptyTable = "No records found.";
            table2.draw();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same URL for both tables as shown below, see [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qexwxLc2/2/) for demonstration.

```
var table1 = $('#example1').DataTable({
    ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu'
});

var table2 = $('#example2').DataTable({
    ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu'
});
```

However to avoid making two requests, the better approach would be to get the data once and add it to corresponding tables later as shown below, see [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qexwxLc2/1/) for demonstration.

```
var table1 = $('#example1').DataTable();    
var table2 = $('#example2').DataTable();  

$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu', function(json){
   table1.rows.add(json.data).draw();
   table2.rows.add(json.data).draw();        
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, exactly what i needed.